# What is the origin of Dream's helm in Neil Gaiman's "The Sandman"?

Tags: neil-gaiman, the-sandman

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dream_(character)) states that it is the head and spine of a defeated enemy:

> In battle he wears a helm made from the skull and backbone of a defeated enemy. This helm, which resembles a World War II-era gas mask, is also his sigil in the galleries of the other Endless ...

Is there anything more known?

[image: Dream's Helm]

Comment: I know you're just quoting the Wikipedia page but surely that actually resembles a World War _I_ era gas mask.

Answer (score 6):

Dream explains the story of the helmet and the Gates of Horn and Ivory on *The Sandman: Overture* #3.

What is now the Helm of Dream was once the skull of a god. Said god, along with another one, once came to the Dreaming and proclaimed themselves its masters. They took Dream by surprise and imprisoned him.

Long story short, with the help of Desire and Alianora, the gods were defeated, and Dream fashioned the gates from their horns and the helmet from one of the gods' skull, to remind himself to be vigilant.

[image]